# SQL Server 2005 Express edition Output keyword syntax

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-express

I'm playing with the Output keyword in SQL Serer 2005 Express.  I've written the following query:

```
Declare @tempTable as Table(masterLotDB datetime)
Insert  into dbo.tblMasterLot (RecordCreation)
Values ('2009-10-02')
OUTPUT INSERTED.RecordCreation
into @tempTable
```

I get a syntax error of Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 6
Incorrect syntax near 'OUTPUT'. I've tried various combinations.

The query works without the OUTPUT stuff (i.e. it puts a new record in tblMasterLot,  There is nothing special about tblMasterLot.RecordCreation other than being defined 'not null'.  It's not a primary key or identity.

1. What's going on? Any chance 'OUTPUT' is not really supported in SQL Express 2005?
2. Any tutorials on OUTPUT? (especially in conjuntion with Insert).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The OUTPUT clause should come before VALUES

See Example A [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564(SQL.90).aspx)

Following up:
I reproduced your original 'incorrect syntax near OUTPUT' error using your code.  However, by changing the order of the clauses, it works fine.  Here's my code:

```
create table #tmp_test (recordCreation datetime)

Declare @tempTable as Table(masterLotDB datetime)

Insert  into #tmp_test (RecordCreation)
OUTPUT INSERTED.RecordCreation into @tempTable
Values ('2009-10-02')
```

Output:
    (1 row(s) affected)

Comment: I don't believe that is the answer. In this case Values corresponds to what you are putting in the first table ('tblMasterLot'). However, I think it's related to this.  I saw that the MSDN documentation often shows the use of VALUES after OUTPUT.  But what specifically would I put in this case? I did try your suggestion and got an error of "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'into'."

Answer (score 1):

Output Inserted. doesnot work with Express edition.

Try with *@@IDENTITY* instead

Replace the script

```
Declare @tempTable as Table(masterLotDB datetime)

Insert  into #tmp_test (RecordCreation)
OUTPUT INSERTED.RecordCreation into @tempTable
Values ('2009-10-02')
```

With

```
DECLARE @TempDate DATETIME

INSERT INTO #tmp_test (RecordCreation)
VALUES ('2009-10-02')

SET @TempDate = @@IDENTITY

SELECT @TempDate
```